# Custom comparer for priority_queue object in a class

Tags: c++, lambda, operator-overloading, priority-queue, functor

I have a class that's structured like the following skeleton code.

```
class custom
{
private:
  struct info
  {
    // define some stuff
  };
  std::priority_queue<info, vector<info>, custom_comparer_t> pq;
}
```

I am wondering if there's a standard for how the `custom_comparer_t` in this case should be defined? Would it be best to use a lambda function, a functor, or perhaps overload the `<` or `>` operator in `info`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::priority_queue` template parameters according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue):

```cpp
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::vector<T>,
    class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> class priority_queue;
```

The `Compare` template parameter of `std::priority_queue` must meet the [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) concept requirements. And `std::priority_queue` couldn't use the `T::operator()()` because:

1. It would break the other STL `<algorithm>` functions.
2. `T` could be a POD type or a user defined types and the result will be in a complex implementation of `std::priority_queue`.

And of curse, you could use a functor for the `Compare`:

```cpp
class custom {
 private:
  struct info {
    // define some stuff
    bool operator()(info const&, info const&) const {
      return false;
    }
  };

 private:
  using custom_comparer_t = info;
  std::priority_queue<info, std::vector<info>, custom_comparer_t> pq;
};
```

Comment: I see. I typically use functors and lambdas for custom classes. In this case, would either of these be better than the other?

Comment: @roulette01, I edit the answer, check out it again, please.

Comment: Could you add in something about maybe why a functor is more advantageous here than a lambda function?

Comment: @roulette01, Sorry. I don't know the exact answer to the design. But I could guess that is because we couldn't pass a lambda as a template parameter before C++20.

Comment: What is the purpose of `using custom_comparer_t = info;`? Is it just to be more explicit that you're going to use this as a custom comparer in the priority queue on top of being the type of objects that's being stored in the PQ?

Comment: @roulette01, Yes.